# get from csv or xml with multiple adresses their geocode

Tags: xml, google-maps, csv, geolocation, geocoding

anybody know how can i parse a csv or xml document with multiple addresses, to get their latitude and longitude?
im talkin'about 300+ addresses..
thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using one of the big mapping apis

- [Google Mapping API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)
- [Bing Maps API](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx)
- [Yahoo Maps API](http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/)

from your code that is parsing the documents.

pseudo code:

```
foreach(node in xmlfile)
{
    //send the parsed address, city, state and postal code to the mapping api.  Use returned data to set Lat/Long
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot Abe.im gonna cycle 300 addresses in few time, there is't a limit on the number of request for google api?

Comment: Usually there is a limit.  You'll have to check but the last time I used Google I think it was 3k a day (or maybe 30k?).  And there were some limitations on how quickly you could send the requests too so watch out for that.  Whatever the limits are I think you will be safe if you're just doing around 1000 addresses.